# Running driver-select script gives Error 1 and 2

Tags: networking

I am trying to install an Atheros driver update and I am using this package: `compat-wireless-2012-11-13-pc`.

I have not installed Ubuntu on disc, but am running it from the USB, running this code:

```bash
./scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
```

This runs a bunch of stuff. At the end I get `Error 1` and `Error 2` and still Ubuntu does not recognize my driver, even upon reboot. What else am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

The driver alx doesn't exist in that version of compat-wireless. It is in later versions which may or may not compile depending on your Ubuntu version. For example, alx is present in compat-wireless-3.5.4-1-snpc which compiles perfectly in Ubuntu 12.10 but probably not in earlier versions.

When you get errors at 'make,' it isn't going to build the driver correctly, so stop.

Please be sure you have the prerequisites build-essential and linux-headers-generic installed.